# Android: Rendering fails - can't pick simple resource from dimens.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, rendering

I am having rendering problems - for some reason, resource isn't getting picked up from dimens.xml. This is detailed in the below pic:

[image]

Any insights? Many thanks folks in anticipation!

In view of the comment by a community member, who advised that I should have all the resource names in lowercase letters, I have to say/enquire the following:
1) all my resource names are a mix a of lowercase and uppercase letters, for example:

```html
<dimen name="LL_subheading1_marginTop">24dp</dimen>
<dimen name="btnCalculate_paddingTop">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="TV_VariableNames_textSize">35sp</dimen>
```

... and they have worked fine. Does this mean that they just have worked fine just by chance, or am I doing something wrong; and

2) i wud be very happy if someone please could share the document where it says that all the resource names should strictly be in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It is not valid resource name. You can't use uppercase. Change textSize to either textsize or text_size</strike>
Sorry, wrong idea.

Comment: thanks @xklakoux - but i have been using a mix of lower and uppercase all along - works fine!

Comment: You're obviously right, I misunderstood. It's the resource file names that can't use uppercase letters. Do you happen to have other dimens.xml files in your project for other configuration?

Comment: Yes - I do have other dimens.xml. Do you think it could be causing conflict?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure why. Could you post contents of your dimens.xml files? Also would be fair to try to clean build the project and invalidate caches and restart android studio.

Comment: Have done the clean, clearing caches, restart android studio a number of times ... the other bit is dimension.xml ... Will post